# AutoMapper problem with custom convert from source to destination

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper to map my db models with my api models. But I have a problem with custom mapping. I'll try to explain my problem:

So I have the db and api models like this:

```cs
public class ApiModel
{
    public List<ApiSubModel> Colors { get; set; }
}

public class DbModel
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Settings { get; set; }
}
```

Generally the `DbModel` `Settings` property is the serialized version of the `ApiModel` . So I want to achieve that with a custom convert when creating the maping:

Startup.cs:

```cs
services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
```

Mapper profile class:

```cs
internal class DbToApiMapping : Profile
    {
        public DbToApiMapping()
        {
            CreateMap<ApiModel, DbModel>()
                .ConvertUsing((source, dest, context) => new DbModel
                {
                    Type = context.Items["Type"].ToString(),
                    Settings = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source)
                });
                

            CreateMap<DbModel, ApiModel>()
                .ConstructUsing((source, context) => 
                {
                    var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiModel>(source.Settings);
                    return new ApiModel
                    {
                        Colors = res.Colors
                    };
                });


        }


    }
```

For the first map I use it like this:

```cs
var settings = modelMapper.Map<DbModel>(req.Settings, opt => opt.Items["Type"] = "Setpoint");
```

For the second map I use it like that:

```cs
var ss = modelMapper.Map<ApiModel>(settings.Settings);
```

The error I get when try to map is as follows:

```
Message: 
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException : Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Object -> ApiModel
System.Object -> CommonLibrary.Models.ApiModel
```

I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong...but I can't quite catch what to look exactly. For the second mapping I tried with `.ConvertUsing()` method, but the error is the same.

Can someone help with this one.

Thanks in advance

Julian

**---EDIT---**
As suggested in the comments I tried without the DI. Here is the code:

```cs
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration( cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<ApiModel, DbModel>()
                .ConvertUsing((source, dest, context) => new DbModel
                {
                    Type = context.Items["Type"].ToString(),
                    Settings = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source)
                });
                cfg.CreateMap<DbModel, ApiModel>()
                .ConstructUsing((source, context) =>
                {
                    var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiModel>(source.Settings);
                    return new ApiModel
                    {
                        Colors = res.Colors
                    };
                });
            });

            var modelMapper = config.CreateMapper();

            var apiObj = new ApiModel
            {
                Colors = new List<ApiSubModel>
                {
                    new ApiSubModel
                    {
                        SomeProp = "Test",
                        SubModel = new ApiSubSubModel
                        {
                            IntProp = 3,
                            StringProp = "Alabala"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            DbModel dbRes = modelMapper.Map<DbModel>(apiObj, opt => opt.Items["Type"] = "Setpoint");

            var dbObj = new DbModel
            {
                Type = "Setpoint",
                Settings = "{\"Colors\":[{\"SomeProp\":\"Test\",\"SubModel\":{\"IntProp\":3,\"StringProp\":\"Alabala\"}}]}"
            };

            var apiRes = modelMapper.Map<ApiModel>(dbObj);
            Console.WriteLine(dbRes.Settings);
            Console.WriteLine(apiRes.Colors[0].SomeProp);
            Console.WriteLine(apiRes.Colors[0].SubModel.StringProp);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class ApiModel
    {
        public List<ApiSubModel> Colors { get; set; }
    }

    public class DbModel
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Settings { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApiSubModel
    {
        public string SomeProp { get; set; }
        public ApiSubSubModel SubModel { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApiSubSubModel
    {
        public int IntProp { get; set; }
        public string StringProp { get; set; }
    }
```

It IS working, but there is something strange, when I want to debug the program and put a break point after `var apiRes = modelMapper.Map<ApiModel>(dbObj);` and try to debug the value of `apiRes` it says `apiRes error CS0103: The name 'apiRes' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Try it without DI, so you can isolate the issue.

Comment: I made a separate project without DI, it works with some strange behavior. I'm also wondering what might be the problem with that DI.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Comment: Yes, this is the way I configure the DI `services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())`

Comment: And yet there is no such code in the docs :)

Comment: `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.dll` this is the dll file. And from it I see the signature of the extension method I use: `public static IServiceCollection AddAutoMapper(this IServiceCollection services, params Assembly[] assemblies);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find my mistake, and I have to admit it is a silly one, but took me a lot of time to figure. The problem is in the line `var ss = modelMapper.Map<ApiModel>(settings.Settings);`
See I have the `Profile` like this:

```cs
CreateMap<DbModel, ApiModel>()
                .ConstructUsing((source, context) => 
                {
                    var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiModel>(source.Settings);
                    return new ApiModel
                    {
                        Colors = res.Colors
                    };
                });
```

It expects the source to be a `DbModel` object, but in fact I pass a property of this object which is in fact a string. And I do not have defined that kind of mapping, that is why I get the error.

The right usage have to be: `var ss = modelMapper.Map<ApiModel>(settings);`

So thanks for all your suggestions!

Regards,
Julian

Answer (score 2):

I tweaked your code a bit and now it works(although I had to use my own JSON and my own SubApiModel) but you can ask me about it in the comments if you're unsure

My models

```
public class ApiModel
    {
        public List<ApiSubModel> Colors { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApiSubModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class DbModel
    {
        public DbModel(string type, string settings)
        {
            Type = type;
            Settings = settings;
        }

        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Settings { get; set; }
    }
```

and my JSON

```
{
  Colors: 
  [
     {
        "Name": "AMunim"
     }
   ]
}
```

and this is my mapping configuration:

```
.CreateMap<DbModel, ApiModel>()
                .ConstructUsing((source, context) =>
                {
                    var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiModel>(source.Settings);
                    return res;
                });
```

This basically deserializes the whole JSON and since it has a property Color which is a list of ApiSubModels, I can simply convert the whole string to Object(of type ApiModel).

This is my complete testing code

```
using AutoMapper;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using StackAnswers;
using StackAnswers.Automapper;
using System.Numerics;

DbModel dbModel = new DbModel("very important type", "{Colors: [{\"Name\": \"AMunim\"}]}");
MapperConfiguration config = new(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<DbModel, ApiModel>()
                .ConstructUsing((source, context) =>
                {
                    var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiModel>(source.Settings);
                    return res;
                });
});


Mapper mapper = new(config);

ApiModel apiModel = mapper.Map<DbModel, ApiModel>(dbModel);

Console.WriteLine(apiModel.Colors.Count);
Console.WriteLine(apiModel.Colors.FirstOrDefault()?.Name);
Console.Read();
```

and the output: [image: evidence showing it works]

**EDIT**
You can register your profiles/Mappings individually and force DI to use that i.e. register that

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(c => {
    //profile
    c.AddProfile<DbToApiMapping>();
    //mappings
    c.CreateMap<DbModel, ApiModel>()
                .ConstructUsing((source, context) =>
                {
                    var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiModel>(source.Settings);
                    return res;
                });

});
//now register this instance
services.AddSingleton<IMapper>(s => config.CreateMapper());
```

Now when you request this service you will get the instance with configuration applied in your ctor

```
public class BadClass
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    BadClass(IMapper mapper)
    {
         _mapper = mapper;
    }


    public void HandleFunction()
    {
       //here you can use this
       ApiModel apiModel = _mapper.Map<DbModel, ApiModel>(dbModel);
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for the code, but I said in the edited part of the question, that this way it works in both directions. But when it is applied with DI it is not working

Comment: the problem is, that the assignment is to use `.AddAutoMapper()` extensions methods

Comment: then add it like this, `services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(DbToApiMapping))` and now try again. If this fixes your issue please mark this answer as accepted

Comment: @Julian did this work?

Comment: nope, I've tried...it is still the same

Comment: thanks for all your time and suggestions. The problem with that comes from the way I use it. I use it from the testing env (xUnit), and seems that when you change the code for the tested object, somehow the framework caches the old code. The solution was to clean the project and rebuild it again.